# Recovering Range Parameters

Tags: code-golf

### Description

You are given the results of a range function where every element has been rounded down to the nearest whole number. Your goal is to recover the original list.

For example, the following function (in Python3) will produce an input for your program:

```
from numpy import arange, floor
def floored_range(A, B, C):
    return list(floor(arange(A, B, C)))
```

The output of your program should be a valid guess of the original data. Here, valid guess means that it must exactly match the input when floored and it must be a possible output of a range function (ie, when graphed it must form a perfectly straight line).

### Examples

```
Input: [1,2,3,4]  
Output: [1,2,3,4]  

Input: [1,2,3,4]  
Output: [1.9,2.7,3.5,4.3]  

Input: [1,2,3,4,5,5]  
Output: [1.9,2.7,3.5,4.3,5.1,5.9]  

Input: [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]  
Output: [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5]  

Input: [1,1,2,3,3,4]  
Output: [1,1.7,2.4,3.1,3.8,4.5]

Input: [56, 54, 52, 50, 48, 45, 43, 41, 39, 37, 35, 32, 30, 28, 26, 24, 22, 19, 17, 15, 13, 11]
Output: [56.7  , 54.541, 52.382, 50.223, 48.064, 45.905, 43.746, 41.587,
   39.428, 37.269, 35.11 , 32.951, 30.792, 28.633, 26.474, 24.315,
   22.156, 19.997, 17.838, 15.679, 13.52 , 11.361]
```

Comment: You should require at least one of the output value to be decimal, otherwise we could return the input everytime.

Comment: @Therandomguy _when graphed it must form a perfectly straight line_

Comment: Oooooh. i didn't see this. It should spice things up.

Comment: it's always guaranteed that the input is valid? e.g. `1,1,2,2,3,3,10,99`

Comment: @Rod you can assume that you will always get a valid input

Comment: Will the range before rounding down always be non-decreasing? Or can it be something like `[1, 0, -1]`? Also, will it always start at `1`?

Comment: the difference between the elements will always be `<=1`?

Comment: Using the formula in the question, `A, B, C` can be any three floats. The input floored range can, for example, start at `56.7`, end at `10.2` and have a step size of `-2.159`. The only thing that matters is that the points you output, when floored, exactly match the input. I've added an example showing that.

Comment: This can be done in linear time.

Comment: @KyleGullion I took the liberty to modify the second test case, feel free to rollback if you disagree with it

Comment: I can see some numerical issues here.

Comment: @Rod As I see it, the point of the original second test case was to illustrate that several outputs are possible for the same input

Comment: @LuisMendo fair enough

Comment: @Rod Just keep both.

Comment: It's probably too late to add as a requirement, but I'd love to see something that can handle a [dataset like this](https://gist.github.com/kgullion/fb2e812ad1e60c21ed0813c94fa2daee). I didn't consider the random guessing approach when coming up with the problem. C'est la vie...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 82 bytes

```matlab
function y=f(x)
while any(floor(y=linspace(x(1)+rand,x(end)+rand,numel(x)))-x),end
```

Running time is non-deterministic, but the code ends in finite time with probability 1.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##fY3NasMwEITveYq9lEh0DZVktc0hTxJyEJZEBe4q2E5jP707pj@HQnr4QMx@o6ndFD7SuuardFOpQssxq1nvbm@lTxRkUbmvdVDLsS8yXkKX1KyMfhyCRJ5Vkvj9lut76tHUupk1I18BPZDUiSSlmCLlOlCg36WYchHERahMI9WbUMboLpbxorI6GbbsuD1r/RXtm6bZ679n9uzPdNfZrM3bzH@@Mj/SPcU/M/kWWPDE1L4CDxwwTO4AXgAyB8fBsXAsehY9i8zAMXAMHIOeMVhbPwE)

#### Explanation

The code defines a `function` of `x` that outputs `y`. The function consists of a `while` loop.

In each iteration, the right amount (`numel(x)`) of linearly spaced values are generated (`linspace`), starting at `x(1)+rand` and ending at `x(end)+rand`. These two calls to the `rand` function give random offsets between `0` and `1`, which are applied to the initial and final values of `x`.

The loop is repeated for as long as `any` of the `floor`ed results differs (`-`)  from the corresponding entry in `x`.

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY3BasMwEETv@YrtIUSiMmQlu00P/pKSg7FWVOCugu00zte7ExJKT@3hgZh9oyn93H3Juqaz9nMuStc2mcVuLh95EEpDKaO5tkPW6dT1YhbD9nnsNLrFiMbHW8@fMqBl7VO7OOQroC1pmUlFokRKZaSOflaipKyIs1KeJyoXpYTBTczTySTzzs674OqjtfdoV1XVzv4634SbAuk/Lfz1U/PiqKmBB3tH9QE0IAB2FN7AK0AW4AQ4Ho5Hz6PnkTEchsNwGD1mrK3f) using `a!=b` instead of `any(a-b)`

Comment: @ovs Unfortunately that doesn't work, because it stops as soon as _some_ output entry equals that in the input, not when _all_ do. See second entry of the second output in your link

Comment: (because it's provable that the probability for a randomly chosen line to be valid is nonzero)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 189 bytes

```python
def f(l):
 R=range(len(l));e=1-1e-9
 for j in R:
  for I in range(j*4):
   i=I//4;L=[((l[i]+I//2%2*e)*(x-j)-(l[j]+I%2*e)*(x-i))/(i-j)for x in R]
   if[x//1 for x in L]==l:return L
 return l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDLboMwEEX3fIU3lWx6EfErCUT@gEhZZYtYVKpJjSwSISqRrydj0qab7uaeOXMXc7tPX9dBL8un71jHo6gzdnbjx3DxPPqBgDh4Jwvpiypj3XVkPQsDO5O2pmNKT73PTbpmLLhjWZrDyTWcxya07xTVm8q9yPlc9KIg2hN9oSBEyQNtUuO89rdrUdfMZSnZC59a52I9@ul7pJCxnykuyYjJaLJGQkHDtPhvhIV9xgQSStD8If17YLewpCvYDcwexsLQRkJX0DtoC03yBmoPtYUyUAqygtxBWkgNKamkrW9jGCaeHiuWBw)

Cubic time.

Has some numerical issues.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 86 bytes

```r
function(n){while(any(n-(x=seq(n[1]+runif(1),tail(n,1)+runif(1),l=sum(n|1)))%/%1))0;x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcjBCoJQEAXQfV/RRrhDIzXlLv2ScCHi0IPXjdRHRvbtr3atDpwx@7Yusyf2c7gTlPfzGuKAji@wxNJMwwO8WLsbE4PDROcuRFBN/hWbKd3A1USk2Bc/Duflkx09TI960kpk46gkfwE)

R port of [Luis Mendo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162561/67312); it does issue a number of warnings because of `any` coercing to `logical` but these can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 168 bytes

```python
def f(l):r=range(len(l));g=lambda n:[(l[b]+n-l[a])/(b-a)for a in r for b in r if b>a]or[0];s=(max(g(-1))+min(g(1)))/2;m=min(a*s-l[a]for a in r);return[a*s-m for a in r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDNboQgFIX3fQqW0DlmBGR@NPRFCAvMqDVBNGiT9uktzKSV1Xe/czkJLD/b5xzkvj@6nvTUszrq6MLQUd@FNLJm0N5N7cORUBvqTWtPofDGWXambeFYP0fiyBhIJBnbF449aT@cnaMpbbNqOrlvOtCCM3aaxpAwETuLZtJ5dO/rs/LoYk3stq8YTI4mcgR2z@wTmzfDISBRWfwjFNRrzCKrLKtDyb8L6gKV1gVUieqGSqFKCYe8Q14hFWRaLiFuEBeICkKA38Gv4ApcgvNUYusljmGjHvnn4LX247qlxy406adMZ/8F) Explanation: `g` calculates the limiting values for `C` that lie just outside the range for `A` and `B` to exist. The average is then taken to give a usable value for `C`, and then the lowest possible range is then generated.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 94 bytes, assuming input length > 1

```javascript
f=x=>(t=x.map(_=>a+=b,b=x[1]+(c=Math.random)(a=x[0]+c())-a,a-=b)).map(Math.floor)+''==x?t:f(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcvdCoJAEIbh827EGXaUrI6CsSvoCkRiXN1@UEd0ib37TYWOgk6/53tf8pbZTs/Rp4M2bYyOIZBwKPeVActX8Y9skqHRHgGpXiCvjAVMhTyHrJcRblyI4Zok5RqRC7@tW@k61QlNkjCHiz87CBitDrN2bdbpHRyUOR3oSKcKcfcjq626@J/H8dvHDw)

97 bytes

```javascript
f=x=>(t=x.map(_=>a+=b,b=x[1]+(c=Math.random)(a=x[0]+c())-a||0,a-=b)).map(Math.floor)+''==x?t:f(x)
```

Comment: [Fails for `[1]`.](https://tio.run/##HYxbCoMwEACP4y55UH8La0/QExSRTTR9ELMSQ8nto/g7w8yP/7z7/N2KSTIvrQWCqpnq6zYq8PTk8rGZ0ywrAmp3in5UHtCwLlTtyhtMNLAip9mQQ6ShXPQqQxTJqLqOqD7KPUDF5iXtEhcb5Q0Bzh1iOwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 bytes

```
ṾṚ”.;V×LḶ$}+©1ị$}IEȧḞ⁼¥ʋ
0ç1#®ḷ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AU0Asv9qZWxsef//4bm@4bma4oCdLjtWw5dM4bi2JH0rwqkx4buLJH1JRcin4bie4oG8wqXKiwoww6cxI8Ku4bi3////WzEsMSwyLDMsMyw0XQ)

**Warning**: Floating-point inaccuracies.

Comment: Doesn't terminate for `[1,2,3,4,5,5]` in 30 seconds on TIO. Some explanation please?

Comment: @user202729 Most probably floating-point inaccuracies. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 212 bytes

```python
def f(l):
 C=[(0,1.,0,1.)]
 for a,A,b,B in C:
  x,y=(A+a)/2,(B+b)/2;r=[l[0]+x+i*(l[-1]+y-l[0]-x)/(~-len(l)or 1)for i in range(len(l))];C+=[(x,A,y,B),(a,x,y,B),(x,A,b,y),(a,x,b,y)]
  if[n//1for n in r]==l:return r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLLboMwELzzFT7aYUmwCX3Khya/0BtClaNAiuRA5FIJLv31dLakSZXmsF57dvbtw9i/d605HrdVLWrp1VMk1raQKek58aHKSNRdEI5eaEMr0bRiDY4YaLTyJXZqYUiu4g30c7CFL9IyHuJmJn2R6DIeE0aSQS3kV@KrFhkQTCsO2XCw4NpdJSeLKp/XMZIPyDXSSpF0NJxuw0/@8YTxDYWJpi7axUJztPYnWmmtfwpV/xnwODb7Qxd6sXf9e8QN7qYGg@VOoSfe3h0kU@a177pAQSEGiRBFh9C0PZwKXaq/LzKU0fIKY5RxWG7asn8@@R2JfAkxkJTE8gGSQzKIJpE9Qu4hwDJwMnAMOAZ@Bn4GmAZHg6PB0fDTN0ulnHLGT/PAzLfdPmL1Wn30H7YoIx7h22UhOk15Uo42dmLPJyXVDCbS6ewKTvJIeFtc5igdfsHmetF/vFAivplJFW/yvJLfmmKO9X8v5ak35708c9XxGw)